# Xpath Extractor in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

<a class="orange" href="#" id='acctNumLink66'
onclick=submitURLTargetWindowAsync('A_4','AmsServlet.jsp?ni=-1355636085&from=searchPage');> 001010000003666663477
Wor suv Recover (400900)

How to extract the "ni"  value from the above html response body ? Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do this using single alone XPath Extractor, the maximum it will give you is the whole [`onclick` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp) value

[image]

once done you can use i.e. [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter/) to extract the `ni` value from the `onclick` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

[image]

Demo:

[image]